# Angular not grabbing elements by class name when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to get the `document.getElementsByClassName('side-nav-link-ref');` elements in my angular `html` view and It keeps returning empty. I’ve narrowed it down to the `<ng-container>` that I have doing a `ngfor` loop to display all the values in the array (Its creating a dropdown list). The loop is executing and displaying the page in the proper `html` tags and classes.

```
  <div #testElm>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of list">
       <p>This is a test 1</p>
       <p class="test-link">This is a test 2</p>
       <p>This is a test 3</p>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
```

When I run `document.getElementsByClassName('side-nav-link-ref');` in the dev-tools console I get the desired results but when I run it in my project it shows me that It doesn’t see anything.

**.ts file**

```
@ViewChild('testElm') testElm!: ElementRef;

 list: any [] = [1];
 
  ngOnInit(): void {   
    this._testFunction(); 
  }
 
  _testFunction() { 
    const test: any = document.getElementsByClassName('test-link');
    for (let index = 0; index < test.length; index++) {      
      console.log('sTest: ' + test.length); 
      
    }
  }
```

The result should

Comment: The parent is `this.testElm`, experiment `console.log(this.testElm)` to showing the DOM estructure.

Comment: @IvanFerrer when I do that I'm getting `undefined`. After looking into it, I guess you cant `console.log` the @ViewChild because its ngOnInit(){} runs before Angular initializes the component's views and child views.

Comment: Use ngAfterViewInit?

Comment: `implements OnInit, AfterViewInit { ... }` and use `ngAfterViewInit() { this._testFunction() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngOnInit is called when the component is loaded, but the view is still loading. You need ngAfterViewInit because you're trying to manipulate the dom/view. See [Angular lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

Also your ts file has the wrong classname.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use @ViewChildren and templateRef something like that [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tmkqst?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: updated it so there is a `@ViewChild` and it doesnt seem to see the elements still.